# Deciding responsive layouts

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, media-queries, form-fields

I know this is not a real question but I am unable to find anything on internet related to this. Please read my question if you find it not suitable to stackoverflow, you can go ahead and mark this as closed.

I have a html page which is fluid. It has certain form fields. They stretch from left to right. What I am told to do is to convert that layout to responsive. I can write my own media queries. What I am unable to do is decide the responsive behavior i.e. padding, position and dimension in proportion with respect to various screen sizes.

I have created a fiddle to represent my page. Please let me know if there is any standard guidelines to decide a responsive behavior for standard layouts.

In firefox we can press `Ctrl + Shft + M` to check various resolution options.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main-container">
    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <label>First name:</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </section>
        <section>
            <label>Last name:</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.main-container {width:99%; height:auto; display:table; background-color:red; margin:0 auto}
.container {display:table-cell; padding:0 80px; border:1px solid #000}
section {display:table; width:100%; padding:10px 0}
label {display:table-cell; width:100px}
input {width:100%; border:1px solid gray}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pEgqc/2/

jsfiddle in full screen: http://jsfiddle.net/pEgqc/2/embedded/result/

Comment: Once you have designed for a screen resolution(ex 1280 px * 1280 px) and then you target screen 640px * 640px your all dimensions go half to match the targeted screen. While the Position may vary from screen size to screen size as per requirement.

Comment: write your media queries for the breakpoints you want, add the selectors with the same rulesets as above to all of the queries, then open the page (i prefer chrome, but it looks like you use firefox) and open the element inspector (developer tools) resize the window to your different breakpoints and make adjustments as needed in the inspector until you have it how you want it to look, then make those adjustments in the actual css file.

Answer (score 1):

An excellent resource for you would be [Brad Frosts Pattern Lab - Forms](http://bradfrost.github.io/this-is-responsive/patterns.html#forms).

The best fit for you would be this one in particular http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/full/DmnlJ